# Can I shade a plugin with ant (preferably using the maven-shade-plugin)?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ant

I am coding a spigot plugin and I need to use an external library, however this isn't a plugin in itself. So I need to shade it in my .jar.

I already shaded it with maven and it works like a charm when I use `mvn clean install`. However, I am also using ant to auto build my projects from eclipse and I like using as it is fast, but ant doesn't shade it like maven. I tried re-generating the maven-build.xml with `mvn ant:ant`, but still nothing.

I tried one-jar for ant and [this ant plugin](https://github.com/lyubomyr-shaydariv/ant-shade-task), but they kinda ignored the library I need.

My build.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- ===================================================================== -->
<!-- Ant build file (http://ant.apache.org/) for Ant 1.6.2 or above.        -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->

<project name="Alchemic-Library" default="make" basedir=".">

  <import file="maven-build.xml"/>

  <property name="one-jar.dist.dir" value="${basedir}/one-jar"/>
  <import file="${one-jar.dist.dir}/one-jar-ant-task.xml" optional="true"/>

  <!-- ====================================================================== -->
  <!-- Help target                                                            -->
  <!-- ====================================================================== -->

  <target name="help">
    <echo message="Please run: $ant -projecthelp"/>
  </target>
  <target name="make">
    <antcall><target name="package"></target></antcall>
    <antcall><target name="copy-to-test-server"></target></antcall>
  </target>
  <target name="test">
    <available file="${basedir}//..//Test-Server//plugins//${maven.build.finalName}.jar" property="test.test"></available>
  </target>

  <target name="copy-to-test-server" depends="test" if="test.test">
    <echo message="Copying '${maven.build.dir}/${maven.build.finalName}.jar' to plugins folder"/>
    <copy file="${maven.build.dir}/${maven.build.finalName}.jar" todir="${basedir}//..//Test-Server//plugins"/>
  </target>

  <target name="maven">
    <exec dir="${basedir}" executable="cmd">
        <arg value="/C"/>
        <arg value="mvn clean install" />  
    </exec>  
  </target>
</project>
```

Portion of my pom.xml:

```xml
<plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <configuration>

        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

I thought the ant builder automatically grabs the pom.xml and uses that, but apparently not.
Can any of you help?

Comment: You should make a decision either to use Ant or Maven but not both...apart from that if you got the impression Maven is slower than you usually doing more than you think or doing it wrong... Furthermore the maven-shade-plugin only exist in Maven not in Ant ...nor that I know of the task etc which can do something similar in Ant ...

Comment: The only reason I use Ant is because I want to automatically build the .jar file actually and I coudn't find any good alternative, do you have one perhaps? Also: when auto building with the ant builder, it took about 900 ms, when using maven (only using mvn package, no clean, no install) it takes about 4.8 s.

Comment: A jar file can simply being build with Maven..apart from that if you use `mvn package` you are doing much more than simply compiling the code..you are running tests (suppose you have some) etc. copying resources...based on the pom you have given you also creating source package etc. ? The time is not really comparable....

Comment: That's true yeah, anyway I can disable the tests? I realise it is not exactly ideal, I just want to auto build with and immediately test my code. And do you happen to have ant building alternatives?

Comment: You can disable the tests via `-DskipTests` but you can also skip the compiling also via `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` but aren't you are working in an IDE and running the tests from time to time?

Comment: Disabling the the tests helped a bit, so did the source packaging. And I am running the tests from time to time yes, that's why I want to auto build my project

Comment: Do you work in IDE? If so you should not run the Maven build from inside IDE (Eclipse)...there you have the tests....so no need to run a full build only command line or on a CI system....

Comment: You mean like the debug launching? I sadly am unable to do that since I am coding a spigot _plugin_, which means I have to load a .jar file to use it, and debugging doesn't allow that...